# Solidus installation issue with rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, ruby-on-rails-6, solidus

I have been trying out to install Solidus on my mac, for which i followed the documentation, https://guides.solidus.io/developers/getting-started/first-time-installation.html

I am using ruby version **ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]** and rails version **6.0.0**

After adding

```
gem 'solidus'
gem 'solidus_auth_devise'
```

While trying `bundle install` I am facing the following issue

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    actionpack (= 6.0.0)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 6.0.0)

    solidus was resolved to 2.5.0.beta1, which depends on
      solidus_core (= 2.5.0.beta1) was resolved to 2.5.0.beta1, which depends on
        actionpack (~> 5.1.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    rails (= 6.0.0)

  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 6.0.0)

    solidus was resolved to 1.0.0.pre, which depends on
      solidus_core (= 1.0.0.pre) was resolved to 1.0.0.pre, which depends on
        rails (~> 4.2.0)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Am I missing something or messed up with rails version? I can understand that it requries rails version 5.1.0, but is there no support for rails 6 with solidus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solidus `2.10.0.beta1` has just been released. This way you can try it out with Rails 6 as well by using:

```
gem 'solidus', '~> 2.10.0.beta1'
```

in your Gemfile.